# Issue in plotting a 3d graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I am struggling to design a 3d  graph for four parameters, I have three parameters x, y, and z. Parameter x, y, and z are in the range of 0 and 1 while k parameter is categorical value 0 or 1. My data is in the following format [data-csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aSxadRtFZO5MzwSM6bfAVlCiPvi_ufHJ/view?usp=sharing)

Code

```
data = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",", names=["x", "y","z","k"])
x, y, z = zip(*data)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Optimal-Selection')
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.set_zlim(0,1)
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(np.array(x), np.array(y), np.array(z),cmap='viridis')
fig.colorbar(surf,shrink=0.5, aspect=9)
plt.show()
```

Runtime Error:

```
RuntimeError: Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: input inconsistency (exitcode=1); use python verbose option (-v) to see original qhull error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this any close to what you were looking for?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
list (data)
x = data [:,0]
y = data [:,1]
z = data [:,2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Optimal-Selection')
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.set_zlim(0,1)
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z,cmap='viridis')
fig.colorbar(surf,shrink=0.5, aspect=9)
plt.show()
```

[image]